# How to update data in firestore with Node.js, within a map-array

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set').

I am trying to update the endTime in the script and i want to do it for each user then calculate the total amount of hours worked and update it in a field called 'totalTime'.

```
const {
        initializeApp,
        applicationDefault,
        cert,
    } = require("firebase-admin/app");
    const {
        getFirestore,
        Timestamp,
        FieldValue,
    } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
    xxxxxx
    };
    
    const serviceAccount = require("./fitness-69af3-firebase-adminsdk-c3hmg-c7fda98049.json");
    
    initializeApp({
        credential: cert(serviceAccount),
    });
    const db = getFirestore();
    
    const age = "30";
    
    async function main() {
        const fitnessRef = db.collection("/food");
    
        const snapshot = await fitnessRef
            .where("role", "==", "junior")
            .where("age", "==", age)
            .get();
    
        if (snapshot.empty) {
            console.log("No matching documents.");
        }
    
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            let doc1 = doc.data();
            let schedules = doc1.userInfo.schedule;
            console.log(schedules);
    
            const res = schedules.ref.set(
                {
                endTime: "17:30",
                startTime: "09:00",
                // totalTime: "{endTime - startTime}"
            },              { merge: true }
            );
        });
    }
    
main();
```

[image: data]

Answer (score 1):

The `ref` property is a `DocumentReference`, and thus only exists on the full document, not on individual fields in there. So you will have to call `doc.ref.update(...)`, with the field(s) you want to update.

Moreover, you can't update an individual item in an array in Firestore. You will have to read the entire array from the document, update the item in that array, and then write the entire array back to the database.

Comment: ty for taking the time to answer, so would i need to store the array into a variable and then edit the array and then push it to Firestore. If so are there any pointers on how i would be able to do that

Comment: Both my answer and your comment outlined step-by-step what is needed for this use-case, so I recommend giving it a try. If you get stuck, report back with the specific code of what you tried and somebody can probably help with that too.